# accessing range of values in arduino array

Tags: arrays, arduino

I have data packet coming in like this in Arduino.

Data: 12345678901234

I can access the 5th value using the code below.

```
id = sx1272.packet_received.data[4];
```

My question is how do I access a rang of values?

I tried this, but the colon throws an error.

```
char[2] id; 

if( sx1272.packet_received.length > 4 )
{
id = sx1272.packet_received.data[4:5]; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays in `C++` don't allow this syntax.

What you should do is something like this:

```
char[2] id; 

if( sx1272.packet_received.length > 5 )
{
    id[0] = sx1272.packet_received.data[4];
    id[1] = sx1272.packet_received.data[5];
}
```